# Why was I assigned the Mortarboard badge while my activity tab shows only 196 reputation points today?

Tags: support, badges, daily-reputation-badges

Why was I assigned the [Mortarboard badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67402#67402)  while my activity tab shows only 196 daily reputation points today?

It says that I must earn 200 daily reputation points to get this badge.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

That particular badge family does not pay any attention to negative reputation events you encounter that day. So it's ignoring the two downvotes you've received, which results in you being at 200 for the day.

Comment: Does it means downvotes reduce the daily rep cap below 200? Or is it just for the badge calculation?

Comment: @Mindwin it's just for the badge. The OP can still earn the 4 missing points to hit the rep cap.