# The Mortarboard badge description confuses me

Tags: discussion, badges, daily-reputation-badges

The description for the Mortarboard badge is:

> Earn at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day

This is confusing to me because, in my mind, the concepts of "at least" and "maximum" are antonymous.

Should "at least" be deleted from the description, or is it possible to earn more than the maximum daily reputation in a day?

Comment: [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208106/347191)  is the last time it was changed due to confusion

Comment: That link seems to imply that "the daily maximum" is clickable, but in the grid shown by "let me pick my next badge to track" the text "the daily maximum" is definitely NOT clickable

Comment: The hyperlink is visible in the text [here on the main Badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges). It is stripped out when you're using the badge selector, since you wouldn't be able to click on it anyway.

Comment: *Earn the maximum daily reputation (200)*

Answer (score 34):

Re-reading this a couple of times, trying to ignore all of my pre-existing knowledge, I can definitely see how this description would be confusing.

The problem is that the badge description is trying to do too many things. In addition to describing the qualifications for the badge, it is *also* trying to educate you about the reputation cap.

There is not actually a contradiction here. The Mortarboard badge is awarded if you earn 200 reputation in a single day. *Normally*, the maximum reputation you can earn in a day is 200, since that's what the reputation cap is set at, and this amount is sufficient to earn you the badge. However, it is *possible* to earn more than 200 reputation in a day because certain windfalls are exempt from the reputation cap (including the +15 from having your answer accepted, and any reputation you might get from a bounty). So, if you hit the reputation cap by earning 200 reputation in a day, and then pick up *more* reputation from accepts or bounties, you will still earn the Mortarboard badge.

The length of that last paragraph is a problem, though. It's too difficult to explain all of this in a short, terse badge description.

Frankly, I don't see the benefit in trying to squeeze in stuff about the reputation cap there, especially since hitting it is sufficient to earn the badge.

Unless I'm missing something, I don't see any problem with just saying:

> Earn[ed] at least 200 reputation in a single day

It is not really possible to have both completeness and brevity in a badge description. For example, consider that the Mortarboard badge does *not* take into account reputation that you earn from the account association bonus (the +100 rep you get when you create an account on a new site when you are already an established user on another site). It also [doesn't take into account negative reputation events](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336340/366904). And it used to not include reputation earned from Documentation, but it does now.

Should we put all of these caveats in the description, too? Not if we want to keep it readable. This is why we have a community-maintained [list of badges with *full* descriptions on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).

Comment: I think an important part of the badge's description is to explain why the user stopped getting rep at 200. The first time you hit the rep cap, it's confusing. Getting that badge with "the daily maximum" in its description helps to explain what's going on, and I imagine removing it would lead to an uptick in confused meta questions. Finding out about the exceptions which allow more reputation in a day is less important.

Comment: So, conceivably, the badge description/message could just be "Hit the reputation cap for today", right @Dave? Of course, that leads to confusion, too, when you continue to earn reputation *past* hitting the reputation cap. This is the problem: confusion seems inevitable, since the system is just too complicated. I agree that the exceptions are less important, but people will certainly wonder about them!

Comment: "Hit the upvote reputation cap for today" ?

Comment: Except that, *until* you reach the reputation cap, accepts and other non-upvote-derived reputation still counts toward the reputation cap.

Answer (score 0):

> Earn at least 200 rep

You can earn more than 200.

> the daily maximum

There is a rep cap of 200 which allow you to earn maximum 200 rep **from upvotes.**

You can earn more from accepted answers, bounties, etc.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't the _"(the daily maximum)"_ be removed?

Comment: the daily maximum indicate the rep cap. but you can make a feature request

Comment: I get that, but it is a bit confusing how you can get rep from bounties and upvotes but only the upvotes count for the rep cap (I can see why that's done, but it's still a bit weird). I would make a feature request but this is a very low priority and I don't care that much about it. Maybe OP will.

Comment: Gotta admit; i'm not really bothered about badges, just the description piqued my interest because a quick bit of math on the "200 max" vs Jon Skeet's million rep showed he'd been earning rep on SO for about 5 years before SO was even created. There's a Chuck Norris fact in there somewhere :)

Comment: @CaiusJard, Did you assume that Jon had low reputation when he started? Jon never had 1 rep

Comment: @Drag *"Jon never had 1 rep"* Really? Why not?

Comment: Jon had. but he scored 230 on the very first day and got another upvote(without rep(

Comment: @CaiusJard you mean these? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts